# Which Scheduled Job will run first?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job, schedule

I have two different `Apex Jobs` scheduled at `12:00 AM` as shown below:

[image: Schedule Screenshot]

Which job will run on next day? Will both jobs run one after another or only one job will run on next day?

Both jobs refer to same class.

Comment: in your pic. You can see **Next Scheduled Run** means your both job will run next day as well..

Comment: They will both run asynchronously.

Comment: they will run asynchronously. but not sure about order. but both job will run.

Comment: Thanks for quick response #Ratan #Chris Duncombe #Tushar Sharma
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Both jobs will run on next day but we will not be able to predict the order.

Comment: Correct.  Order is not guaranteed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Apex Scheduler](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) page.

> Salesforce schedules the class for execution at the specified time. Actual execution may be delayed based on service availability.

So as resources become available, your jobs will begin executing, but order is not guaranteed.